# How do I use the for loops to insert only rows that are not inside my main dataframe?

Tags: r

Essentially, I am trying to use the for loops to match the data in a certain column in my sample df against my main df.

sample df:

```
ID   Fruit
F1   Apple
F2   Orange
F3   Banana
```

main df:

```
    ID   Fruit
    F1   Apple
    F3   Banana 
    F4   Pear
    F5   Mangoes
    F6   Grapes
    F7   Watermelon
```

So as you can see here, F2 Orange is actually missing in my main df. My old code was to just to use for loops to check and see if anything in my sample df matches my main df, which will simply stop when it detects Apple and not fill in F2 Orange.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(sample)) {
if (sample[i,1] %in% main$ID) {
stop("Fruits are already in dataframe!")} else {
rbind(sample,main)
  }
}
```

So, what I would need the for loop to do is to insert F2 Orange into the main df while leaving the others intact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the values in `main_df` are unique you can `rbind` `sample_df` and take `unique` rows.

```
unique(rbind(main_df, sample_df))

#  ID      Fruit
#1 F1      Apple
#2 F3     Banana
#3 F4       Pear
#4 F5    Mangoes
#5 F6     Grapes
#6 F7 Watermelon
#8 F2     Orange
```

Using `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(main_df, sample_df) %>% distinct()
```

---

If we want to check for all values in `sample_df` present in `main_df` and notify the user about it, we can use :

```
if(all(do.call(paste, sample_df) %in% do.call(paste, main_df))) 
    stop("Fruits are already in dataframe!")
else 
    unique(rbind(sample_df, main_df))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, I would like to retain the for loop & stop message to inform the user that the fruits are already in the main df if everything in sample matches the main. Is there any way to retain it?

Comment: @user1464667 See update in the answer. Would something like that help? In your current loop you are stopping the loop in the first row itself which means if the first row matches the loop would stop and I think this is not what you want.

Comment: @user1464667 You want to inform the user only after all the fruits have been checked in `sample`? Or do you want to do it for each row. So if first row is present print "Fruits are present" and if not print "Fruits are not present" ?

Comment: Hi Ronak, your second comment was what I wanted and I've found your code useful, albeit not the final solution that I came up with. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `anti_join` to find the rows that are not in the other and then bind that output with the original data

```
library(dplyr)
anti_join(sample_df, main_df) %>%
     bind_rows(main_df, .)
```

Comment: Thanks Akrun for the proposed solution. However, I am trying to retain the for loops as I do have a lot more code encapsulated after the else function. Would like to run them as well after binding on the newly binded rows from sample, if there are new entries. If not, the code would simply stop.

Comment: @user1464667 do you need the one in the updated solution